# How can I figure out why my network configuration is simply ignored?

Tags: debian, networking, ifupdown

I have been running Debian 10 a.k.a. Buster without issues. My problems started when all of a sudden, network connectivity dropped. At that point, NetworkManager was active. I stopped and disabled the service to exclude its interference.

This PC runs KVM VMs in a bridged configuration:

```
$ sudo brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP     enabled interfaces
br1     8000.7446a0a0d47b   no      eno1
                                    vnet0
                                    vnet1
                                    vnet2
                                    vnet3
```

My interfaces file looks like this (leaving out a few comments):

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
(...)
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet manual

auto br1
iface br1 inet manual
bridge_ports eno1
address 192.168.1.27
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.16, 1.1.1.1
```

When I run `systemctl restart networking`, or `ifdown br1; ifup br1`, `br1` ends up with no IP address, both `eno1` and `br1` are down, and there is no default route. Removing the hash signs on the eno1 lines has no effect.

In my desperation, I added this line to the interfaces file: `this line is illegal`. When it comes **before** the loopback block, it causes an expected error message:

```
ifup: /etc/network/interfaces:7: misplaced option
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

When it comes **after** it, it doesn't. It's as if `ifupdown` stopped reading after the loopback configuration. But putting the loopback block at the end of the file still doesn't configure `br1`. I haven't detected any non-printable characters or otherwise strange characters in the file.

To cross the T's, here is the journal:

```
$ sudo journalctl -u -e networking
(...)
-- Reboot --
May 21 09:29:58 jupiter systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
May 21 09:29:59 jupiter ifup[584]: Waiting for br1 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 32 seconds).
May 21 09:30:00 jupiter systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

And setting STP on the bridge doesn't change the behaviour. How about ifup?

```
# type ifup
ifup is /usr/sbin/ifup
# file /usr/sbin/ifup
/usr/sbin/ifup: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=9ac8619bfa91d2b8901228595fa390826c9682c7, stripped
```

**How can I figure out why my network configuration is simply ignored?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From man [The manual Method](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5#The_static_Method):

> The manual Method This method may be used to define interfaces for
> which no configuration is done by default. Such interfaces can be
> configured manually by means of `up` and `down` commands or
> `/etc/network/if-*.d` scripts.

The `address` command is not valid here, but the *bridge-utils* scripts in `/etc/network/if-*.d` still configure all bridge aspects of this interface.

While from [The static Method](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5#The_static_Method):

> This method may be used to define Ethernet interfaces with statically
> allocated IPv4 addresses.
>
> Options
>
> **address** *address*
> Address (dotted quad/netmask) required
>
> [...]

You should change this line:

> ```
> iface br1 inet manual
> ```

into this:

```
iface br1 inet static
```

or alternately leave `manual` and configure manually with `up ip address add ...` and `up ip route add default ...` commands (I wouldn't know how to easily configure `resolv.conf` manually).

Comment: Thanks for unblocking my brain. I confused manual with static. RTFM, I guess.